await asyncio.open_connection(ip, port) stalls until "[WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired" occurs
I am trying to learn about asynchronous bittorrent protocol from this repo. However, when I try to run the program. (With a custom torrent I uploaded, which works on software like qbittorrent).
The code stalls when trying to open a connection. Specifically at line
self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(ip, port)

in pieces.protocol.py
I tried debugging the code. As expected it reaches the line to open connection. Then awaits and starts the 2nd peer. Then awaits again. But the connection for the 2 peers never opens.
